# is $f^{-1}$ of some $G_\delta$ is always $G_\delta$ for any $f$?

Tags: general-topology

> $(a)$ Let $X,Y$ be two topological space. Prove that if $f:X\to Y$ be
>   a map and $B$ is a $G_\delta$ set in $Y$, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is a
>   $G_\delta$ set in $X$.
>
> $(b)$ Let $A\subset X$ and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a map which vanishes
>   precisely on $A$ then $A$ is a closed $G_\delta$ set in $X$.

$(a)$ Since $B$ is $G_\delta$ in $Y$, we can write $\displaystyle B=\bigcap_n B_n$ for some open sets $B_n$ in $Y$. Now $$f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}\bigg(\bigcap_n B_n\bigg)=\bigcap_nf^{-1}(B_n)$$ Now if we could prove each $f^{-1}(B_n)$ is open in $X$ then our proof is complete. But since $f$ is not given to be continuous, I am unable to conclude the argument.

$(b)$ Here if the previous result is true, then in this case $$f^{-1}(\{0\})=A$$ and since $\{0\}$ is closed and $G_\delta$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is $G_\delta$, but as $f$ is not continuous, we can't say $A$ is closed.

How to conclude the two results from here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes authors use the word "map" to imply that the function is continuous. I believe I've seen this convention used in algebraic topology on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you must assume that $f$ is continuous. It is common in topology to assume that "map" means "continuous map". For example, this is a convention used in Hatcher's book on algebraic topology.

Thus (a) follows and (b) follows because $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ and the inverse image $A= f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is also closed, by continuity.